# How to separate logic of a module into multiple projects in XAF

Tags: c#, devexpress, xaf

To separate logic of a XAF module. I decided to break it into some projects projects:

```
Accounting
---Accounting.Module
---Accounting.BusinessModels
---Accounting.Data

Inventory
---Inventory.Module
---Inventory.BusinessModels  ( Contains POCO)
---Inventory.Data            ( Contains DbContext)
```

But unfortunately I cant find the business models of `Accounting.BusinessModles` in the Model Editor of `Accounting.Module`. I've already added required references to the `Accounting.Module` project.

Is it true that XAF just discovers the models inside the `BusinesObjects` folder of `Accounting.Module` project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your projects should be a XAF module which means that they should contain a class that derives XAF ModuleBase. Then XAF is able to recognize your objects wherever you put them.

Comment: Yes, the `Accounting.Module` is a XAF module and has a reference to `Accounting.BusinessModels`. But unfortunately, the model browser doesn't detect the POCO classes in the `Accounting.BusinessModels`

Comment: XAF will load all types and will detect BO for modules only. Your Accounting.BusinessModels i guess its not a module. If its not your need to manually register your BO as described in XAF documentation https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument112847 (see the Add Classes from a Custom Library section)

Comment: I followed the document but unfortunately my assembly: `Accounting.BusinessModels` is not shown in the `Exported Types/Referenced Assemplies`. I've already referenced the `Accounting.BusinessModels` in the `Accounting.Moduel` project. Worth to mention that using the code approach(adding some code to the module's constructor) works fine and the business classes are shown in the BOModels in the designer.

Comment: I've just restarted the Visual Studio and it appeared in the `Reference Assemblies`!